# Add characters in the variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to make the string/varchar variable with value `20061212` to be string/varchar value `2006-12-12 00:00:00`

I can't find the right SQL syntax code to make it happened in SQL Server.

The code can be created as stored procedure or similar in SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT
  LEFT(@string, 4)
  + '-' + SUBSTRING(@string, 5, 2)
  + '-' + SUBSTRING(@string, 7, 2)
  + ' 00:00:00'
```

You *could* cast your string to a DATETIME and then convert it back to a string in your chosen format.  But that would likely be slower than this more explicit option.

```
SELECT
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), CAST(@string AS DATETIME), 120)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [stuff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx)

```
declare @s varchar(8) = '20061212'
select stuff(stuff(@s, 7, 0, '-'), 5, 0, '-')+' 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SUBSTRING() function (detailed here: http://www.sql-statements.com/sql-substring.html) to take apart the original string, and then put the pieces back together with the added dashes & time at the end using the concatenation operator +.

Answer (score 1):

Culture independent variant:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, convert(datetime, '20061212', 112), 120)
```

**BUT** this only valid for DATETIME-allowed range of dates, use `DATETIME2` instead